# $u_n\rightarrow u$ and $\nabla u_n\rightarrow g$ implies $g=\nabla u$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $u_n\in  H^1(\Omega)$ and $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ and one shows that $\nabla u_n$ has a limit in $L^2(\Omega)$, let's say $\nabla u_n\rightarrow g$. I wonder if $g=\nabla u$. Any hint to prove it?

Answer (score 3):

Everything follows from
$$
\langle u,\partial_k\phi\rangle = \lim_n\langle u_n,\partial_k\phi\rangle = -\lim_n\langle\partial_k u_n,\phi\rangle = -\langle g_k,\phi\rangle
$$
for $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you, so in fact you are proving something better, because you have only used weak convergence for both sequences... +1

Comment: Hmm, you're right, actually. However, you want to prove that the graph of the operator $Tu = \nabla u$ is closed. And in a Hilbert space a subspace is closed if and only if it is weakly closed.